# Accessing Pivots Points through a series subscript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

```
my_pivothigh(float _series = high, int _leftBars, int _rightBars) =>
    float _pivotHigh = na
    int _pivotRange = ( _leftBars + _rightBars )
    float _leftEdgeValue = nz(_series[_pivotRange], na)
    if not na(_series) and _leftBars > 0 and _rightBars > 0 and not na(_leftEdgeValue)
        float _possiblePivotHigh = _series[_rightBars]
        float[] _arrayOfSeriesValues = array.new_float(0)
        for _barIndex = _pivotRange to 0
            array.push(_arrayOfSeriesValues, _series[_barIndex])
        //end for
        int _pivotHighRightBars = array.size(_arrayOfSeriesValues) - array.lastindexof(_arrayOfSeriesValues, array.max(_arrayOfSeriesValues)) - 1
        _pivotHigh := ( _pivotHighRightBars == _rightBars ) ? _possiblePivotHigh : na
    //end if
    _pivotHigh
```

Accessing the pivots points through series subscript `[]` would make it easier to access it's historical values and loop through them. Currently the last `_pivotHigh` is accessible. While implementing an array would make it possible to access it's historical values, it is much harder to manipulate the data.

Currently, the last `_pivotHigh` is accessible

```
ph = my_pivothigh(high, 10, 10)
if ph
    label.new(bar_index[10], ph, text=str.tostring(ph))
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How to access historical pivots through the series subscript?